# Does one have to install Ant for running Maven's maven-antrun-plugin?

Tags: java, ant, maven

From [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin-1.4/): "This plugin provides the ability to run Ant tasks from within Maven 2."

Do I need to install Ant to run ant tasks or does the maven plugin already includes Ant? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need to install Ant. Maven will download all required dependencies.